# Find the intersection of the ideals $(x,y)\cap (z,x-t)$ in $k[x,y,z,t]$ where $k$ is algebraically closed field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I got that $(x,y)\cap (z,x-t)=(x(x-t),y(x-t),xz,yz)$, but I am not sure if this is correct. I used the following approach:

We want to find an ideal $I(X)$ which consists of polynomials that vanish on $X$ where $X$ is the union of two planes
$$X_1=\{(0,0,z,t):z,t\in k\}\text{ and }X_2=\{(t,y,0,t):z,t\in k\}.$$
So, I can see that $(x(x-t),y(x-t),xz,yz)\subset I(X)$, and I can consider the polynomial $f\in I(X)$ with $f=f_0+f_1+f_2+\dots$ where $f_i$ is the homogeneous part of $f$ to show that $f\in (x(x-t),y(x-t),xz,yz)$ by using brut force (figuring out how each part $f_i$ looks like as it must vanish on $X$).

Is there a smarter/faster way doing this? What is the general approach of finding generators of an intersection for two ideals $I$ and $J$, i.e. $I\cap J$, where we are given the generators for $I$ and $J$?

Comment: You've made an error: $xz$ is in both ideals, but not in the thing you claim is their intersection.

Comment: @KReiser, yeah, I lost that term. Thank you!

Comment: (also $yz$, by the same logic)

Comment: So, in this case, I just multiplied out the generators. But, for example, $(x,y)\cap (y,z)=(y,xz)$.

Comment: Yes: $IJ\subset I\cap J$ always, and in this case it's an equality. This has been discussed [lots on here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+compute+intersection+of+ideals+site:math.stackexchange.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja2rP656PsAhWQtp4KHfbLAFUQrQIoBHoECAYQBQ&biw=1280&bih=578) and I recommend reading some of those posts (key term: Grobner basis).